# Hibernate Transaction Manager - Java configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I've been beating my head against a wall for awhile now trying to get this to work. I have created the following data access object:

```
public interface GenericDAO<T, ID extends Serializable> {
  T findById(ID id);
  List<T> findAll();
  T save(T entity);
  void update(T entity);
  void delete(T entity);
}

public class GenericHibernateDAO<T, ID extends Serializable> implements GenericDAO<T, ID> {

  private final Class<T> persistentClass;
  private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  public GenericHibernateDAO(final SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
  }

  protected Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  }

  public Class<T> getPersistentClass() {
    return persistentClass;
  }

  @Override
  public T findById(final ID id) {
    return (T) getSession().load(getPersistentClass(), id);
  }

  @Override @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public List<T> findAll() {
    return findByCriteria();
  }

  protected List<T> findByCriteria(final Criterion... criterion) {
    final Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
    for (final Criterion c : criterion) {
      crit.add(c);
    }
    return crit.list();
  }

  @Override
  public T save(final T entity) {
    getSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
    return entity;
  }

  @Override
  public void delete(final T entity) {
    getSession().delete(entity);
  }

  @Override
  public void update(final T entity) {
    getSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
  }
}

@Repository
public class StockHibernateDAO extends GenericHibernateDAO<Stock, String> implements StockDAO {

  @Inject
  public StockHibernateDAO(final SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    super(sessionFactory);
  }
}
```

I'm attempting to set this up with Java Configuration, so here is my configuration to setup my service layer:

```
@Configuration @Profile("hibernate")
@EnableCaching @EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("reference.dao.hibernate")
public class HibernateServiceConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

  @Inject private StockDAO stockDao; //No extra methods, just the base stuff for now

  @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).addScript("classpath:schema.sql").build();
  }

  @Bean
  public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    return new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource()).addAnnotatedClasses(Stock.class)
    .setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true")
    .setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory")
    .setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true")
    .setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true")
    .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect").buildSessionFactory();
  }

  @Override @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
    return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
  }

}
```

Here is the TradingService:

```
@Service
public class TradingServiceImpl implements TradingService {    
  @Inject private StockDAO stockDAO;

  @Override @Transactional
  @CachePut(value = "stockCache", key = "#stock.name")
  public Stock addNewStock(final Stock stock) {
    stockDAO.save(stock);
    return stock;
  }

  @Override @Cacheable(value = "stockCache")
  public Stock getStock(final String stockName) {
    return stockDAO.findById(stockName);
  }

  @Override @CacheEvict(value = "stockCache", key = "#stock.name")
  public void removeStock(final Stock stock) {
    stockDAO.delete(stock);
  }

  @Override @CacheEvict(value = "stockCache", key = "#stock.name")
  public void updateStock(final Stock stock) {
    stockDAO.update(stock);
  }

  @Override
  public List<Stock> getAll() {
    return stockDAO.findAll();
  }
}
```

The saving of a stock only seems to be completed if I add a session.flush() to the save method. The way I understand things, having the TransactionManager and the @Transactional around the service layer method should in fact cause that call to be made for me. What is this configuration missing?

Comment: Remove the @Inject StockDao and annotate that class or its implementation with `@Repository`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are injecting a `Session`

```
  @Bean
  public Session session() {
    return sessionFactory().openSession();
  }
```

Spring cannot add it's transactional behavior around it. Let Spring open the session and do it's business.

Instead of injecting a `Session`, inject a `SessionFactory`. In your DAO, keep a attribute for `SessionFactory` and use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` to acquire a session.

When Spring sees the `@Transactional`, it will get the `SessionFactory`, call `openSession()`, begin a transaction on it, then call your method. When your method returns successfully, it will close that transaction.

You should also probably `@Autowired` the dao in your service class.

Comment: Won't that only work if my DAO is demarcated as @Transactional (i.e. doesn't getCurrentSession() only make sense in a transaction)? As it stands I want to mark my service layer with transactions, and not my DAO layer.

Comment: Doesn't matter who has the @Transactional, by default anything within the method call will be using the same session and transaction.

Comment: Then something still isn't quite right, as I receive the following stack: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:978)
        at reference.dao.hibernate.GenericHibernateDAO.getSession(GenericHibernateDAO.java:25)

Comment: And instead of putting them in the Configuration class, just annotate your Dao and Service implementation as `@Repository` and `@Service`, respectively.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24591/discussion-between-scott-and-sotirios-delimanolis)

Comment: This is correct, but it is important to note -- all of the service layer calls need to be @Transactional for this to work properly.

Comment: You can also annotate at class level to achieve that.